# Bold face the author superscript

Tags: fonts, titles, bold, authblk

I have the following piece of code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\usepackage{authblk}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\bfseries\fontsize{12}{14.4pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\normalfont\itshape\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\Authands{, }

\begin{document}
    \title{\textbf{A review of Machine learning techniques}\vspace{0ex}}
    \author[a*]{Abc}
    \author[b]{Def}
    \author[c]{Ghi\vspace{0ex}}
    \affil[a,b]{XYZ, \vspace{0ex}}
    \affil[c]{UVW\vspace{2ex}}
    \date{}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

I want to boldface the superscript `a*` contained in `[a*]`.

How can it be done?

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not a good idea to want to render the superscript letters in **bold**. The superscript letters are *not* part of the names; making them bold will just confuse your readers. Incidentally, is it really necessary to render the authors' names in bold? Overusing **bold-facing** quickly comes across as shouting, which isn't appreciated by most readers.

Comment: @Mico thanks for your valuable comment but still is it possible to boldface the superscripts here. If yes, how can it be done?Thanks.

Comment: For sure, if you insist on making the letter "a" next to the author's name bold, you should also make it bold subsequently, when it's a prefix to one or more affiliations. Incidentally, I also don't understand why you'd want to render the authors' name -- or, for that matter, the title -- in **bold**. To get back to your question: No, I don't know how boldfacing of the superscript letters may be achieved.

Comment: Off-topic: What is the instruction `\vspace{0ex}` supposed to achieve?

Comment: It is of no use here but as I am a beginner so basically trying to see the effect of this statement. Btw \vspace{0ex} has no affect but \vspace{1ex} has.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to print *all* superscripts in **bold**, simply redefine the way superscripts are handled:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\usepackage{authblk}  

\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\bfseries\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\normalfont\itshape\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\Authands{, }

\makeatletter
% Add \bfseries to author superscript
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\bfseries#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{A review of Machine learning techniques}\vspace{0ex}}
\author[a*]{Abc}
\author[b]{Def}
\author[c]{Ghi\vspace{0ex}}
\affil[a,b]{XYZ, \vspace{0ex}}
\affil[c]{UVW\vspace{2ex}}
\date{}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```